# does stage in javafx produce any event on close

Tags: java, javafx

I need to run a bit of code on the close of my stage or alert box. I know how to achieve this in swing but I'm new to javafx and I'm not really sure what to do. I tried using the setOnCloseRequest method of stage and didn't get any expected result.
Is there any way to add a listener to check close event?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Got it. What I had was a Stage fooStage=new Stage(); fooStage.initModality(Modality.APPLICATION_MODAL); fooStage.showAndWait(); so what wanted was to run some code when I try to close it. So I added fooStage.onCloseRequestProperty().setValue(e -> { //code}); and tada it worked